# ttk Entry widget - validate entry - invalid text entry does not cause reverting to previous text

Tags: python, validation, ttk

Python 3.1

I'm trying to validate that the string input to a ttk.Entry widget can be turned into a float. The simple code below shows that the validate function is successful in its task, and is returning true/false correctly.

I understood it to be the case that if the Entry widget gets 'false' back from its validatecommand, it should revert to whatever was stored in the textvariable before the attempted entry happened.

But that's not happening - the new entry appears, even though it's invalid.

Presumably I am missing something foolish...

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = Tk()

text = StringVar()
text.set('100.0')

def validate(inp):
    print(inp)
    if inp in '0123456789.-+':
        try:
            float(inp)
            print('float')
            return True
        except ValueError:
            print('notfloat')
            return False
    else:
        print('notfloat')
        return False

vcmd = root.register(validate)

a = Entry(textvariable = text,
          validate = 'focusout',
          validatecommand = (vcmd,'%P'))
a.pack()

b = Entry()
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = Tk()

text = StringVar()
text.set('100.0')

def validate(inp):
    try:
        float(inp)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

vcmd = root.register(validate)

a = Entry(textvariable=text,
          validate='key',
          validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'))
a.pack()

b = Entry()
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I used `validate='key'` instead.

and replaced `validate` function. `a in b` check substring `a` in contained in `b`.

```
>>> '100.00' in '0123456789.-+'
False
>>> '100.00' in 'blah blah   100.00  blah blah'
True
```

---

**ALTERNATIVE**

using `focusout`:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root = Tk()

text = StringVar()
text.set('100.0')
last_ok_value = text.get()

def validate(inp):
    global last_ok_value
    try:
        float(inp)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    last_ok_value = inp
    return True

def invalidate():
    text.set(last_ok_value)

vcmd = root.register(validate)
ivcmd = root.register(invalidate)

a = Entry(textvariable=text,
          validate='focusout',
          validatecommand=(vcmd, '%P'),
          invalidcommand=(ivcmd,))
a.pack()

b = Entry()
b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

Using class:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

class FloatEntry(Entry):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        initial_value = kwargs.pop('initial_value', '100.00')
        assert self.validate(initial_value), 'Invalid initial_value given'
        self.last_valid_value = initial_value
        self.text = StringVar(value=initial_value)

        Entry.__init__(self, *args, textvariable=self.text, **kwargs)
        self.vcmd = self.register(self.validate)
        self.ivcmd = self.register(self.invalidate)
        self['validate'] = 'focusout'
        self['validatecommand'] = self.vcmd, '%P',
        self['invalidcommand'] = self.ivcmd,

    def validate(self, inp):
        try:
            float(inp)
        except ValueError:
            return False
        self.last_valid_value = inp
        return True

    def invalidate(self):
        self.text.set(self.last_valid_value)

root = Tk()
FloatEntry(initial_value='100.0').pack()
Entry().pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks - I can see how the changes to the validate function were needed. But can you explain why 'key' works but 'focusout' does not? I would like to use focusout - using 'key' means a temporarily blank entry (e.g. user deletes the default prior to typing their own entry) fails.

Comment: To expand on that - basically, it makes sense for the validation to happen after the user finishes the entry and tries to move on to some other part of my application, not while they're still messing around typing/deleting/whatever in the entry box.

Comment: @Tom, I added an alternative version that use `focusout`. I used temporary variable (`last_ok_value`) to store the last valid input.

Comment: @Tom, With `focusout`, validation is called when focus lost, which is not related to edit. Only `key` is. See [entry - VALIDATION](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TkCmd/entry.htm#M16).

Comment: Yep. That's my problem then. Seems the right way to do it is define an invalidcommand handler that sets the text back to what it was before. (As you suggested, but putting it in an invalidcommand handler rather than as part of the validation handler.)

Comment: @Tom, I updated the alternative solution code to use `invalidcommand`.